# Overloading function call operator () for indexing and assignments of a template object

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am attempting to create a template for a matrix data structure and I would like to have concise and intuitive way to index and assign elements (i.e. 'A(i,j)' returns an element and 'A(i,j)=x' assigns a value to this element.)

Based on other forum threads, I saw that by returning an array element by reference, a function/operator could both return and alter that element in this way.

```
template <typename T, int Rows, int Cols>
    struct Matrix {
        private:
        public:
            const int rows = Rows; //number of rows
            const int cols = Cols; //number of columns
            T data[Rows*Cols];     //contents of matrix

            //Single element indexing and assigment
            T& operator() (int i, int j) {
                return data[ (i-1)*(this->cols) + j ];
            }
    };

int main(){
    const int m = 3;
    const int n = 4;
    Matrix<float, m, n> A;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < A.cols; j++) {
            A(i,j) = 3.14;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This worked perfectly when I tried with an explicitly typed struct (in this case int) rather than a template, however now that I am using a template, the assignment 'A(i,j) = x' has the effect of modifying the indices 'i' and 'j' which usually breaks the loops and causes segmentation faults.

Does anyone know why this is happening and if there is anything I can do to achieve the desired results?

*I am fairly new to c++ so if I am going against best practices for the language feel free to let me know*

Comment: `A(i,j)` can't modufy `i` or `j` from the call site.  They are passed by value so `operator()` gets a copy.  Is there an issue with the code shown?  If so, could you detail more what that issue is?

Comment: `i-1` will cause an array access before the array space, resulting in Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's what I thought, however if I print 'i' and 'j' directly before and after 'A(i,j) = 3.14;' the values change in ways that aren't clear to me. For instance after the first call, 'j' changes from 0 to 1078523331

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Could you elaborate? I tried creating a variable 'int index = (i-1)*(this->cols) + j; ' in the function then returning 'data[index]' and I got the same result.

Comment: Think about what you're doing with `i` and `j`. You're subtracting one from `i`, but not from `j`. Should you be doing the subtraction or not? And if so, should it apply to one or both index variables?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm You're right. I've been thinking in one-indexed languages too much. I see that the negative index must have been returning the address of 'j' which led to the index changing in the program rather than the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula used for indexing into `data` is incorrect.

Update your function to return `data[0]` always but print the index. The output will make it clear that you are not using the right index.

```
T& operator() (int i, int j) {
    int index = (i-1)*(this->cols) + j;
    std::cout << "Index: " << index << std::endl;
    
    return data[0];  // This is wrong but that's not the
                     // purpose of this suggested change.
}
```

Useful link: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

**PS** The correct index is `i*(this->cols) + j`.

Comment: Good catch! I've been using Fortran too much lately. The corruption of the indices confused me and threw me off from the real problem which was simply 0 vs 1 based indexing.

Comment: @DanielFust, I can see how that can lead to problems.

Comment: In this particular case, the parentheses (and the `this->`) actually make the expression *substantially harder* to read and, I suspect, contributed to the introduction of the bug. Properly written, the expression reads as `return data[i * cols + j];` and by its simplicity this is self-evidently correct (confusion of col-major vs row-major storage notwithstanding). This is actually a really neat example that adding redundant parentheses doesn’t always improve readability, on the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

> the assignment `A(i,j) = x` has the effect of modifying the indices `i` and `j` which usually breaks the loops and causes segmentation faults.
>
> if I print `i` and `j` directly before and after `A(i,j) = 3.14;` the values change in ways that aren't clear to me. For instance after the first call, `j` changes from 0 to 1078523331

That means you are **corrupting memory**. Writing to an array element that is *out of bounds* will do that.

Your array is 0-indexed. Your `i` and `j` variables start at 0.  But you are subtracting `-1` from the `i` value.  So, what do you think happens when you try to use `(i-1)` in the calculation to get the array index?

Well, let's find out - the very first element you are trying to access is `A(0,0)`, so:

```
  data[ (i-1)*(this->cols) + j ]
= data[ (0-1)*(4) + 0 ]
= data[ (-1)*(4) + 0 ]
= data[ -4 + 0 ]
= data[ -4 ]
```

There is no array element at index `-4`!  You are returning a reference to memory that is located `4*sizeof(T)` bytes *before* the `data[]` array.

To fix this, you need to change the calculation to this instead:

`(i * this->cols) + j`

Now, the result will be correct for `A(0,0)` (and all other inputs that are `0 <= i < rows` and `0 <= j < cols`):

```
  data[ (i * this->cols) + j ]
= data[ (0 * 4) + 0 ]
= data[ 0 + 0 ]
= data[ 0 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The corruption of the index distracted me from the root cause, but it makes sense in hindsight since 'j' was likely stored in that preceding memory address.